# UIToolbar Resizing causes weird UIBarButtonItem size in Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

When I create and add a UIToolBar and UIBarButton items, how can I get the toolbar and items to appear properly in both orientations. This is what I have so far:

```
self.toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44)]autorelease];
self.toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.deleteButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(deleteButtonClicked)] autorelease];
self.deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

self.shareButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButtonClicked)] autorelease];
self.shareButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.shareButton,flexibleSpace,self.deleteButton,nil];
[self.toolbar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

As you can see from the images, the UIBarButtonItems look correct in portrait, but weirdly squished and off center (especially the trash icon), in landscape. Is there an obvious solution I'm missing, or do I have to do manual resizing to get this right?

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]

It's a subtle difference, but here's what it should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Can you show what you think this *should* look like?

Comment: jtbandes: Just updated with a third screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, at least until iOS 5 is to use the `UINavigationController`'s built in toolbar instead of creating your own. The built in toolbar will resize correctly and automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the `Autoresizing` option in the `Size inspector` both for the UIToolBar and the buttons. `UIToolBar` might also have a checkmark set for `Autoresize subviews` uncheck that so it does not influence your buttons.