# UIBarButtonItems are normal in UINavigationBar and resized in UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I use this code for customization UIBarButtonItems:

```
backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barButtonImage"];
backImage = [backImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

All of navigation bars look fine
[image]

But toolbars have resized items in strange way:
[image]

All of UIBarButtonItems are defined in storyboard without any custom views. How can I remove this resizing?

Comment: maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6729230/1702413